# How to change font of language using IBus?

Tags: fonts

I use 3 languages using IBus input in Ubuntu 13.10. How can I choose a custom font for one of the languages?

[image: Image of my Text Entry window]

Changing font in this window only temorarily changes the font of input. When I close this window and open again, font is again set back to the default value. Is this some bug?

Answer (score 0):

That definitely sounds like a bug in either gnome-settings-daemon (which saves settings) or gnome-control-center (which presents the user interface).

Comment: Does that mean, there is some CLI way to do it? If yes, what is it?